# If InputBox equals Value1 then connect to Database1

Tags: vba, excel, ssms

I'm trying to create a VBA code that would connect to a specific database based on the user's input. E.g. if a user enters **DB1** into the prompt, the code will run the following query: **SELECT * FROM MyServerName.DB1.dbo.Table**

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DB As Variant
    DB = InputBox("Please enter the Database Name.")

    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServerName;" & _
                                   "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Unsuccessful attempt to use the Else/If statement: 

    if '" & DB & "' = "DB1" then
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM MyServerName.DB1.dbo.Table ;")

    elseif '" & DB & "' = "DB2" then
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM MyServerName.DB2.dbo.Table ;")

    else
    MsgBox "No records returned. Enter the correct Database Name.", vbCritical
    End If

    If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing  

End Sub
```

The connection itself is working just fine when I use the select statement without Else/If. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `DB` variable to decide which database to use

`Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [MyServerName].[" & DB & "].dbo.table ;")`

Comment: It worked! Pretty sure I've tried this before... Probably messed up the syntax back then. Thank you, Mr JF!

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Syntax can be a bit tricky sometimes with VBA :)